# D3 - Staggered colour change

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've been stuck on this for a while. I have a series of rectangles like so:

[image: 1]

and I want to incrementally change the colour of each triangle, so the first one would change colour, a pause, then the second one, another pause, then third, etc. This has been fine for changing to a single colour. However currently when my method terminates, all the fills of the rectangles remain to be colour it was changed to like so:

[image: 2]

Is there a way to incrementally change my rectangles to orange then revert back to blue again after some delay? So the transition should look something like this:

[image], pause for n amount of seconds, then

[image], pause

[image], pause

[image], pause

[image], pause

[image], pause

[image]

This is one of my attempts:

```
        var x = ["a", "f", "t", "q", "g", "y", "p"];
        var w = (x.length + 1) * 50;
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)

            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
                //This successfully changes all the rect into orange ones
                svg.select("#rect" + i)
                   .data([i])   
                   .transition()
                   .delay(i * 1000) 
                   .attr("x", (i * 45) + 45)
                   .attr("y", "0px")
                   .attr("width", "40px")
                   .attr("height", "40px")
                   .attr("fill", "rgb(255, 116, 56)");   

                //I was hoping this would revert each rect to the blue colour, this did not work                           
                svg.select("#rect" + i-1)
                   .data([i-1]) 
                   .transition()
                   .delay(i* 2500) 
                   .attr("x", ((i-1) * 45) + 45)
                   .attr("y", "0px")
                   .attr("width", "40px")
                   .attr("height", "40px")
                   .attr("fill", "rgb(0, 0, 50)");

            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code isn't really using D3 the way it's intended to be used. Your attempt is applying imperative programming methodologies where D3 is designed to support a more declarative approach. The crux is that you want to take advantage of the data-join framework and declarative styling/transitions that d3 provides.

Check this example out http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/YbMmQ/ and follow this tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234 and see if this other approach makes more sense.

In the Fiddle, there is an update method that joins the selected rectangles to the data array, and specifies how D3 should handle elements of the array when they are added vs updated. For this example, on the add we specify their position and default color of blue. On update, we only need to change the color. Outside of the update function, we change the "selected" rectangle and each time update is called, the color of the rectangles are changed such that the selected rectangle is orange. This change is applied with a duration of 500 ms so that whenever a rectangle's color is changed from blue->orange or orange->blue, the transition takes place smoothly over 500ms.

If you know nothing will ever be added to the data array, you could move the "//Enter" portion of the code outside of the update block so that it only gets called once. For this example, it would support adding elements to the data array, but not removing them since no "exit()" behavior is defined.

```
function update(data) {
    var rect = svg.selectAll("rect").data(x);

    //Update
    rect
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return (i === selected)? "rgb(255, 116, 56)" : "rgb(0, 0, 50)"; });

    //Enter
    rect.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return (i * 45); })
        .attr("y", "0px")
        .attr("width", "40px")
        .attr("height", "40px")
        .attr("fill", "rgb(0, 0, 50)");
}
```

The specific problem with your code is related to the fact that you are manually iterating over the array of data, selecting the elements of the dom you want to manipulate, and applying a duration-based transition to those elements. This is very much how you'd do it with a framework like jQuery. It looks like you're confusing transition durations with delays, and so what you are actually doing is looping over all the elements in your array and changing the colors to orange and then immediately back to blue, the transition never really has time to animate the change.

Anyhow, like I said check out the Fiddle I provided and the tutorial on the general pattern to use with d3 for more insight into how to build these kinds of visualizations with d3. Good luck!